# Filter by multiple data attribute elements

Tags: jquery, attributes

I've got some list items i want to filter using selects if the data attribute has all of the select option values not just if it has one or another.

```
<li class="filterme" data-type="Primary Academy Physical KS1">item 1</li>
<li class="filterme" data-type="Secondary Academy Physical KS2">item</li>
<li class="filterme" data-type="Secondary Academy Physical KS1">item 1</li>
<li class="filterme" data-type="Academy Physical KS1">item 1</li>
```

I have some select boxes firing an onchange event which first hides all items

```
$('.filterme').hide();
```

And i then want to show if a data attribute contains all values passed to it. I tried

```
$(".filterme[data-type*='" + Secondary && Physical && KS1 + "']").show();
```

Which i want to show this one

```
<li class="filterme" data-type="Secondary Academy Physical KS1">item 1</li>
```

But it doesnt show any matches
I can get it to work with just one value, but how do i check if a data attribute contains multiple values, not OR but AND?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(".filterme").each(function() {
  if ($(this).data("type").indexOf("Secondary") > -1 && $(this).data("type").indexOf("Physical") > -1 && $(this).data("type").indexOf("KS1") > -1) {
    console.log($(this).data("type"));
  }
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/vv75u8nt/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks. I changed 

console.log($(this).data("type"));

for

$(this).show();

and its perfect

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use multiple selectors then filter on them.

item 1
etc

Then you can filter on:

```
// data-type1 AND data-type-2
if ($(this).find('[data-type1="Primary"][data-type-2="Academy"]').length) {
    //stuff
}

// data-type1 OR data-type-2
if ($(this).find('[data-type1="Primary"],[data-type-2="Academy"]').length) {
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer by @omarjebari, but for programmers who want to return multiple elements with different data attribute and different data attribute value were both **ARE NOT** always present

```
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1'></p>
<p class='my-class' data-attribute2='2'></p>

// data-attribute1 OR data-attribute2
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"],[data-attribute2="${secondID}"]`);
```

When looking to return multiple elements with different data attribute and different data attribute value were both **ARE** always present

```
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1' data-attribute2='1'></p>
<p class='my-class' data-attribute1='1' data-attribute2='2'></p>

// data-attribute1 AND data-attribute2
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"][data-attribute2="${secondID}"]`);
```

The placement of the **comma** is crucial to differentiate between finding with **OR** or an **AND** argument.

---

It also works for elements who have the same data attribute but with different attribute value

```
$(".my-class").filter(`[data-attribute1="${firstID}"],[data-attribute1="${secondID}"]`);
```