# How do I filter multiple list items using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, filter

How to create 2 checkboxes, displaying (i.e.) 1. Food and 2. Musician…

Where
1) if both checkboxes are checked, food and musicians are displayed;
2) if food is checked and musician is unchecked, the element is still visible, because it contains food, dispite it also contains musician;
3) if musician is checked and food is unchecked, it is also still visible, because it contains musician, dispite it also contains food;
4) if both food and musician are unchecked, the li item disappears.

My html is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="filterSection">
<li>
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="Food"/>
<label>Food</label>
</li>
<li>
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="Musician"/>
<label>Musician</label>
</li>
</ul>

<ul id="itemsToFilter">
<li data-type="Food">Food</li>
<li data-type="Musician">Musician</li>
<li data-type="Food Musician">Food & Musician</li>
<ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And the following javascript code (integrated below the two lists):

```
<script>
// get all of our list items
var itemsToFilter = document.querySelectorAll("#itemsToFilter li");
  
//setup click event handlers on our checkboxes
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".filterSection li input");
  
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", filterItems, false);
    checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
}
  
// the event handler!
function filterItems(e) {
    var clickedItem = e.target;
      
    if (clickedItem.checked == true) {
        hideOrShowItems(clickedItem.value, "hideItem", "showItem");
    } else if (clickedItem.checked == false) {
        hideOrShowItems(clickedItem.value, "showItem", "hideItem");
    } else {
        // deal with the indeterminate state if needed
    }
}
  
// add or remove classes to show or hide our content
function hideOrShowItems(itemType, classToRemove, classToAdd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsToFilter.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = itemsToFilter[i];
          
        if (currentItem.getAttribute("data-type") == itemType) {
            removeClass(currentItem, classToRemove);
            addClass(currentItem, classToAdd);
        }
    }
}
  
//
// Helper functions for adding and removing class values
//
function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;
        
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
        if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
            element.className = classToAdd;
        } else {
            element.className += " " + classToAdd;
        }
    }
}
        
function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;
  
    if (currentClassValue == classToRemove) {
        element.className = "";
        return;
    }
  
    var classValues = currentClassValue.split(" ");
    var filteredList = [];
  
    for (var i = 0 ; i < classValues.length; i++) {
        if (classToRemove != classValues[i]) {
            filteredList.push(classValues[i]);
        }
    }
  
    element.className = filteredList.join(" ");
}
</script>
```

I found out that in css you can do the following:

```
#itemsToFilter li[data-type*=Food] {background-color: green;}
#itemsToFilter li[data-type*=Musician] {background-color: yellow;}
```

(The asterisk causes one or multiple data-type attributes to be recognised)

No problems there, so I'm interested in the javascript-part:

Where
1) if both checkboxes are checked, food and musicians are displayed;
2) if food is checked and musician is unchecked, the element is still visible, because it contains food, dispite it also contains musician;
3) if musician is checked and food is unchecked, it is also still visible, because it contains musician, dispite it also contains food;
4) if both food and musician are unchecked, the li item disappears.

I want this without having to make a new checkbox called 'Food Musician'. Which could be done by adding

```
#itemsToFilter li[data-type*='Food Musician'] {background:pink;}
```

So only working with the checkboxes 'Food' and 'Musician'.

See or follow this example on http://test.kompagniekistemaker.nl

My question was raised after reading this article from Kirupa:
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/filtering_items_in_a_list.htm

I also found this example, which is kinda what I want:
[Filter by multiple data attribute elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510489/filter-by-multiple-data-attribute-elements)

Winning answer gets a bar of chocolate.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `if` statement like this:

```
if (currentItem.getAttribute("data-type").indexOf(itemType) !== -1)
```

I'm pretty sure that you know what it's doing. It searches for a substring in your data attribute. `indexOf()` returns position of first character of substring if found or `-1` if a substring was not found. Does it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A friend solved the problem using this piece of javascript. Every piece is explained separately.

In short:
If I create a checkbox in an ul with a class of '.filterSection' corresponding with another ul containing a li-element with a class of '.itemsToFilter' the following happens:

1. if no checkbox is selected, it will show everything of that specific ul
2. if one or more checkboxes is selected, it will show the content of the corresponding checkbox
3. If you want only one li-element in your ul, you can add an 'invisible' extra li-element using the display:none; attribute in css and let it be 'checked="true"' in html. This way there will always be a checked element in your list of seemingly one item, causing the single visible li-element to behave the same as li elements in a list of two or more li-elements. If you don't do this, your one li-element will always be visible, because when it's unchecked, it will display everything (rule 1, above).

   var sections;
   var items;

   init();

   // Initializing function
   function init() {
       // Get the checkbox sections and the items to filter
       sections = query('.filterSection');
       items = query('.itemsToFilter li');

   ```
   // Create a section for every group of checkboxes
   for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
       sections[i] = query('input', sections[i]);

       // Loop over the checkboxes in a section
       for (var j = 0; j < sections[i].length; j++) {

           // Add event listener (filter on change)
           sections[i][j].addEventListener('change', filter);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   // Function that is called when a checkbox is clicked or unclicked
   function filter() {
       // Get the selected checkboxes
       var selection = getSelection();

   ```
   // Loop over all items
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       // Initially, every item will be shown
       var show = true;

       // Get the tags associated with the item
       var tags = items[i].dataset.type.split(',');

       // Loop over each tag section
       for (var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++) {

           // If the section has no checked boxes, it will be ignored
           if (selection[j].length == 0) continue;

           // Hide the item, unless we tell it to be shown later
           var allow = false;

           // Loop over the associated tags
           for (var k = 0; k < tags.length; k++) {

               // If the tag is also one that has been selected, allow the item to be shown
               if (selection[j].indexOf(tags[k]) > -1) {
                   allow = true;
               }
           }

           // If one of the tags was disallowed, hide the item. Do not keep checking as this is unnecessary
           if (!allow) {
               show = false;
               break;
           }
       }

       // Add the appropriate class
       if (!show) items[i].classList.add('hideItem');
       else items[i].classList.remove('hideItem');
   }
   ```

   }

   // Function to get the selected checkboxes
   function getSelection() {
       // Here we will keep track of checked boxes
       var selection = [];

   ```
   // Loop over each section
   for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
       // Initialize an empty selection list per section
       selection[i] = [];

       // Loop over the checkboxes in this section
       for (var j = 0; j < sections[i].length; j++) {

           // Get the checkbox
           var checkbox = sections[i][j];

           // If the checkbox is checked, add it to the selection list
           if (checkbox.checked) selection[i].push(checkbox.value);
       }
   }

   return selection;
   ```

   }

   // Utility function to query the DOM and return elements
   function query(q, container) {
       // If no container was given, revert to the entire document
       container = container || document;

   ```
   // Query the container
   var results = container.querySelectorAll(q);

   // Return the results as an array
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(results);
   ```

   }